# Sympy parser doesn't pass the right constant

Tags: python, parsing, sympy

```
>>>from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import (parse_expr, ... standard_transformations, function_exponentiation)
>>> transformations = standard_transformations + (function_exponentiation,)
>>>parse= parse_expr('2x', transformations=transformations)
parse = parse_expr("2x", transformations=transformations)
>>> parse.coeff("x",0)
2
>>> parse.coeff("x")
2
>>> parse = parse_expr("2x+5", transformations=transformations)
>>> parse.coeff("x")
2
>>> parse.coeff("x",0)
5
```

I am quite new to python and sympy.
The problem here is that any time I want to get the constant 0 it returns the coefficient of x. But this doesn't happen when the constant is not zero(shown in the second equation). I am trying to use this to solve linear equations in which I don't know the user input. But it keeps giving me a wrong answer when there is no constant attached after x.

Answer (score 0):

There is some discussion on Github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5657

One way to do it is to convert to a polynomial:

```
>>> (2*x + 3).as_poly()
Poly(2*x + 3, x, domain='ZZ')
>>> (2*x + 3).as_poly().nth(0)
3
>>> (2*x + 3).as_poly().nth(1)
2
>>> (2*x).as_poly().nth(0)
0
>>> (2*x).as_poly().nth(1)
2
```

Unfortunately converting to a `Poly` first is slower.